# Kotlin Room Database Implementation

Tags: android-room

I am currently trying to implement a Room Database into my project however I am unsure of how to actually start the database and be able to access it. I have the following classes but unsure of what's next. Thanks in advance for any help you can send my way.

GameData.kt

```
package com.example.quizshowfinal.roomdb

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "GameData")
data class GameData(

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    val category: String?,
    val clue: String?,
    val response: String?
)
```

GameDataDAO.kt

```
package com.example.quizshowfinal.roomdb

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update

@Dao
interface GameDataDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(gameData: GameData)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(gameData: GameData)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(gameData: GameData)

    @Query("Select * FROM GameData ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getRandom(): List<GameData>

    @Query("Select * FROM GameData WHERE category IS :currentCategory ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getRandomFromCategory(currentCategory: String): List<GameData>
}
```

QuizShowDatabase.kt

```
package com.example.quizshowfinal.roomdb

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [(GameData::class)], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class QuizShowDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun gameDataDao(): GameDataDAO

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: QuizShowDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): QuizShowDatabase {

            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        QuizShowDatabase::class.java,
                        "quizshow_database"
                    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()

                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameDataRepository.kt

```
package com.example.quizshowfinal.roomdb

class GameDataRepository ( private val repoGameDataDAO: GameDataDAO) : RepoInterface {

    override suspend fun insert(gameData: GameData) =
        repoGameDataDAO.insert(gameData)

    override suspend fun update(gameData: GameData) =
        repoGameDataDAO.update(gameData)

    override suspend fun delete(gameData: GameData) =
        repoGameDataDAO.delete(gameData)

    override suspend fun getRandom() =
        repoGameDataDAO.getRandom()

    override suspend fun getRandomFromCategory(currentCategory: String) =
        repoGameDataDAO.getRandomFromCategory(currentCategory)

}
```

RepoInterface.kt

```
package com.example.quizshowfinal.roomdb

interface RepoInterface {

    suspend fun insert(gameData: GameData)


    suspend fun update(gameData: GameData)


    suspend fun delete(gameData: GameData)


    suspend fun getRandom(): List<GameData>


    suspend fun getRandomFromCategory(currentCategory: String): List<GameData>
}
```

AppContainer.kt

```
package com.example.quizshowfinal.roomdb

import android.content.Context


interface AppContainer {
    val gameDataRepository: GameDataRepository
}


class AppDataContainer(private val context: Context) : AppContainer {

    override val gameDataRepository: GameDataRepository by lazy {
        GameDataRepository(QuizShowDatabase.getInstance(context).gameDataDao())
    }
}
```

All the examples I've tried to follow are using the database differently than I intend to so I can't figure out what I should do differently. I plan on using a prepopulated database and while I've included the basic CRUD implementations I will only ever be doing the 2 queries I have in the DAO and I just need access to the strings in the DB so I can assign them to variables in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create the pre-populated database EXACTLY according to what Room expects.

   1. If you compile the project successfully (what matters are the `@Entity` annotated class and that the `@Database` annotated class includes the `@Entity` annotated classes in the entities parameter)
   2. Find, the java(generated) folder and within it locate the sub folder that includes a class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with `_Impl`. Then find the `createAllTables` method, this will have statements that include the SQL that Room would use to create the tables i.e. EXACTLY what Room expects.
2. ensure that the database is just the 1 file and that there are not files with the same name but suffixed with `-wal` and or `-shm`. If these exist then the database has not been properly closed (use whatever tool you use to properly close the database).
3. copy the file into the assets folder (you may have to create the assets folder).
4. Amended the `databaseBuilder` call to include the `.createFromAsset(the_filename_of_the_asset)`

   1. obviously changing `the_filename_of_asset` to whatever the file name is
5. Run the App ensuring that you attempt to access the database from and activity/fragment

   1. simply obtaining an instance of the `@Database` annotated class does not on it's own open the database. It is not until the database is opened that the asset will be copied from the assets folder.